# DataTables. Plugin Select no funciona

Tags: javascript, nodejs, datatables, select

Tengo el siguiente código de javascript, ejecutado en un entorno node.js.

```
    let alturaScrollY = $(window).height()
        - $('#linksGransIPetits').height()
        - $('#divBotons').height()
        - $('#mesos').height()
        - 60 + 'px';

    let dataID = null;
    let taula = null;

    loadTable(dades);    

    function loadTable(dades) {

        taula = $('#table').DataTable({
            select: 'single',
            "destroy": true,
            "scrollY": alturaScrollY,
            "scrollCollapse": true,
            "paging": false,
            "searching": false,
            "bInfo": false,
            "data": dades,
            //"data": <%- dadesDuesNoviembre %>,
            "columns": [
                {"data": 'id'},
                {"data": 'colectivo'},
                {"data": 'unidad'},
                {"data": 'turno'},
                {"data": 'dia'},
                {"data": 'licencia'},
                {"data": 'cubre'},
                {"data": 'notas'}
            ],
            columnDefs: [
                {targets: 0, visible: false},
                {targets: 1, visible: false}
            ]
        });

        $('#table tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {

            console.log('Inside click listener')

            if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {

                console.log('had Class selected')

                $(this).removeClass('selected');
                idSolicitud = null
                $('#info').text('')
            } else {

                console.log('NOT had Class selected')

                taula.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
                $(this).addClass('selected');
                idSolicitud = $('#table').DataTable().row(this).data().id;
                console.log(idSolicitud)
                $('#info').text(idSolicitud)
            }
        });
    }
```

Hasta aquí, todo correcto. El código se ejecuta como espero. Pero al sustituir "loadTable(dades)" por un bloque switch, quedando:

```
    let alturaScrollY = $(window).height()
        - $('#linksGransIPetits').height()
        - $('#divBotons').height()
        - $('#mesos').height()
        - 60 + 'px';

    let idSolicitud = null;
    let taula = null;

    switch (condition) {
        case 1:
            $('#tab_1').addClass('active');
            loadTable(<%- dades_1 %>);
            break;
        case 2:
            $('#tab_2').addClass('active');
            loadTable(<%- dades_2 %>);
            break;
        case 3:
            $('#tab_3').addClass('active');
            loadTable(<%- dades_3 %>);
            break;
        default:
            break
    }    

    function loadTable(dades) {

        taula = $('#table').DataTable({
            select: 'single',
            "destroy": true,
            "scrollY": alturaScrollY,
            "scrollCollapse": true,
            "paging": false,
            "searching": false,
            "bInfo": false,
            "data": dades,
            //"data": <%- dadesDuesNoviembre %>,
            "columns": [
                {"data": 'data1'},
                {"data": 'data2'},
                {"data": 'data3'},
                {"data": 'data4'}
            ],
            columnDefs: [
                {targets: 0, visible: false}
            ]
        });

        $('#table tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {

            console.log('Inside click listener')

            if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {

                console.log('had Class selected')

                $(this).removeClass('selected');
                idSolicitud = null
                $('#info').text('')
            } else {

                console.log('NOT had Class selected')

                taula.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
                $(this).addClass('selected');
                dataID= $('#table').DataTable().row(this).data().data1;
                console.log(dataID)
                $('#info').text(idSoldataIDicitud)
            }
        });
    }
```

La salida que obtengo en la consola no tiene lógica. Si selecciono, por ejemplo, una línea que no esté seleccionada, obtengo:

Inside click listener
NOT had Class selected
2
Inside click listener
had Class selected

¿Por qué se ejecuta 2 veces el código del bloque $('#table tbody').on( 'click'......?

Y si selecciono una fila que esté seleccionada, la salida es:

Inside click listener
had Class selected
Inside click listener
NOT had Class selected

Llevo horas y horas dándole vueltas y no consigo vislumbrar cuál puede ser el error....

Comment: Prueba poniendo al inicio del párrafo onclick. Lo siguiente: ``event.stopPropagation()``;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('#table tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {` se ejecuta 2 veces (o más) porque se define más de una vez. Cada vez que se ejecuta `loadTable`, se agrega un nuevo "event listener".

La solución sería mover `$('#table tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {` fuera de la función `loadTable`.

Comment: Gracias. Efectivamente es como dices. Yo estaba convencido de que al dibujar de nuevo la tabla, el listener anterior se eliminaba, quedando solo el nuevo. ¡GRACIAS!